# drawing a line between location points

Tags: bing-maps, windows-phone-7

I am following the steps in the below link to locate my location using GPS (point on the map), I got an idea that requires to draw a line between multipule points (ex. a line from point 1 to point 2 to point X .. etc).

What are my options in doing so?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/simplegps.aspx

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a thirdparty library from ESRI. Look for the ESRI Silverlight and Windows Phone SDK. You will need to create an account on the Esri site, but it's for free (and so is the sdk). It has ton of options that the current lib from microsoft doesnt have.

Comment: That's correct but their silverlight / wp7 sdk is hosted here http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/. Arcgis.com is their online portal.